# Why are SQL fieldnames sometimes spelled like `this`?

Tags: sql, backticks

What's the difference between

```
SELECT * FROM `this`
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM this
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The former is escaped, the latter isn't. Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM `FROM`
```

On systems where the the backtick is an escape, that would select from a table called `FROM` (whereas without the backticks, it's a syntax error). Some systems use square brackets instead, e.g., `SELECT * FROM [FROM]`.

Comment: so basically, you should never have a field called FROM but only `FROM`, is that right?

Comment: @Gal: Right. And it'll depend on your platform whether you use backticks for that or some other notation (I've just updated the answer with a bit more detail).

Comment: @James Curran: Thanks, I *just* saw that and went to edit, and you'd beaten me to it!